# Accessibility: On updating UIAlertView's message, the text that Voice over reads does not change?

Tags: ios, accessibility, uialertview

Please refer the code below:

```
UIAlertView *progressAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                  message:@"Message"  
                                  delegate:self 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];


progressAlertView.message=@"Hello, I am the new one";
```

Voice over always reads "Message" and never reads the new message string set in the second line "Hello, I am the new one". There's no way to change this accessibility label of the bodyTextLabel control/subView of UIAlertView.

Any idea how to make UIAlertView change its accessibility labels after its alloc'ed?

Thanks,

-Shilpi

Answer (score 1):

You can use accessibilityTraits as UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently to read updated message. 
it works like:

```
alertObj.accessibilityTraits =   UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this way for set message of **UIAlertView**

```
UIAlertView *progressAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                  message:@"Message"  
                                  delegate:self 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];


[alertView setMessage:@"Hello, I am the new one"];
[alertView show];
```

For More About UIAlertView Refer this 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Comment: I have already read the documentation that you mentioned above. And for your reference alertView.message=@"abc" and [alertView setMessage:@"abc"]; is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the subviews of `UIAlertView` to change single attributes like the accessibility label:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                                message:@"Message"
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

// In a standard UIAlertView there are 2 UILabels and some buttons
// The UILabel with the message is always the 2nd object in the array
NSArray *subviews = alert.subviews;
UILabel *messageLabel = [subviews objectAtIndex:1];
[messageLabel setAccessibilityLabel:@"Some other text"];
```

With this code you only change the accessibility label, so that VoiceOver reads another text but the old text is shown.

In your case you should set the accessibility label to the same as you want to set the message of the `UIAlertView`.

Comment: Accessing internal views is something which Apple does not recommend and in fact, may reject your app if you are using something like this.

Comment: Apple Bug ID# 13095288 has been logged to track this issue